# Conditional type for exctracting the type of a parameter of a function

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have this generic type that I use for extracting the type of the second parameter of a function:

```
type SecondParam<T> = T extends (a: any, b: infer R) => any
  ? R
  : never;
```

It works for most cases:

```
type T1 = SecondParam<(x: any, y: number) => void>; // number
type T2 = SecondParam<(x: any, y: { x: string[] }) => void>; // { x: string[] }
```

<s>But when the second parameter is not present, I want it to give me `void` instead of `{}`:</s>

```
type T3 = SecondParam<(x:any) => any> // is {}, I want void
```

I'm using `SecondParam` to define the type of another function:

```
type F<T> = (p: SecondParam<T>) => void;
type F1 = F<(x: any, y: number) => any>; // (p: number) => void
type F2 = F<(x: any, y: { x: string[] }) => any>; // (p: { x: string[] }) => void
type F3 = F<(x: any) => any>; // is (p: {}}) => void, but I want () => void
```

But it doesn't work well for the last case, when the second parameter is missing.

Comment: this might be a better way of extracting parameters if you can move to 3.0 when it comes out https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type confition `(a: any, b: infer R) => any ? .. : ..`  is always true because omiting paramters doesn't create compile errors see this example which compiles:

```
const abc: (one: string, two: string, three: string) => void = (onlyFirst: string) => { };
```

If you really want `() => void` as type then you'd have to add a new type condition on the SecondParam type. Like this:

```
type SecondParam<T> = T extends (a: any, b: infer R) => any
  ? R
  : never;

type F<T> = T extends (a: any) => any
  ? () => void
  : (p: SecondParam<T>) => void;

type F3 = F<(x: any) => any>; // is () => void
```

If you want type `never` which you can't really assign, then you can change the SecondParam-type like this

```
type SecondParam<T> = T extends (a: any) => any
  ? never
  : T extends (a: any, b: infer R) => any
    ? R
    : never;

// you now, can't pass the second parameter as its never:
const f: F3 = () => { };
f(); // expects 1 argument
```